# Can I create a trigger on LeadShare/ ContactShare table?

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service

What I am trying to accomplish sounds easy and should be needed. Whenever a Lead or Contact is shared with another user, I would like to send an email to the user that has access to another record now. Example: User A shares a record (Manually) with another 2 Users B and C. When that happens I want to send an email to users B and C letting them know that User A has shared the record X with them. I tried creating a trigger on LeadShare but apparently it is not possible. Any help or piece of code will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult one. However the only one way i can think of is using a batch process that has to run every half an hour may be.

You need to store the information when the batch ran last time.May be you can get that using AsyncApexJob or CronJobs.

Then based on last batch process you need to figure out if there were some new sharing records with row cause as 'manual' created. If yes you need to get the user details and send mails to them. Sending mails can be either using some flag on lead/contact or via coding.

Comment: That's basically what I was going to say. Unfortunately, that's the only real solution here.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I thought. That will take me forever to do though..